# Best software for designing prototype model for mass production?

Tags: 3d

Hey I want to create some metal miniatures (think like Monopoly tokens).

That requires a prototype for a mold for casting.

What's a good software for this purpose? (3d-design for physical, organic shaped, artistic product, not animation or what-not).

Comment: Your question does not fit the site very well. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information, [edit] your question and put in more/better requirements. There is no 'best'.

Comment: it depends on the extension the manufacturer support. I mean my local plastic 3d printing supports wavefront files and 3ds. So 3ds is AutoCad or 3d studio max as for OBJ is pretty much anything including blender if i'm correct. Usually blender export to pretty much every basic format these manufacturer uses. Unless very hightech ones require STL or Step or Solidworks files.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your skills set, for really complex organic shapes you can use [geomagic freeform pro](http://geomagic.com/en/products/freeform/overview),in freeform  is possible modeling like a clay sculpting process and make all the modifications in order to create a mould. But something like [siemens nx](http://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/en_us/products/nx/) could be enough if you can construct the product with extrusions and so on. If you have a physical object, you can scan it and make it a 3d solid with something like [geomagic studio](http://geomagic.com/en/products/studio/overview/) or [geomagic design x](http://geomagic.com/en/products-landing-pages/designx). Actually a model from blender 3d or another software like that is useful for that purpose if you know what you want.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be free? If not, I would recommend [Autodesk Fusion 360](http://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/overview). It is surprisingly capable having both solid modeling and surfacing. It runs fine on my laptop without a special graphics card. It is free for students, teachers and educators and is quite reasonable (compared to other professional CAD software) for others as well. There is also extensive training materials.